# Chrome Enterprise Management - Hide Address Bar

Tags: google-chrome, enterprise

So I have used the following syntax for my Desktop Shortcuts for end users to prevent them from accessing the address bar in Chrome:

Target-
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.chrome.com/

Start In - 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.chrome.com/

However the end user can just right click the browser window that pops to open a new browser that has the address bar at the top. Anyone have any registry entries to totally and completely prevent Chrome from ever opening a browser that has the address bar enabled?